# How to read uipicker multiple component when one component is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a 3component ui picker with index,days and time of consultation.

i want to read 2nd and 3rd component value when first component is changed.

What should i do to read 2nd and 3rd component in UIPicker when component 1 is changed?

```
    days=@[@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday"];
self.indexes=@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7"];
timeOfConsultation=@[@"9:00 AM",@"11:00 AM"];

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
       if(component == 0){
        _labelValueIndex.text = [self.indexes objectAtIndex:row];

        // When component 1 is spinned read component 2 and component 3 value even if they are not spinned
   [days objectAtIndex:row];// incorrect value as row variable is like global if i select indexes[1] . i also get days[1] and timeOfConsultation [1]

        // How to read component 2 and component 3 value from component1 change event  

    }else if (component == 1){

        labelValueBookingDay.text = [days objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
        labelValueTimeOfConsultation.text = [timeOfConsultation objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code-

```
NSString *YourselectedTitle = [self.yourArrayName objectAtIndex:[self.yourPickerName selectedRowInComponent:1]];
NSLog(@"%@", YourselectedTitle);
```

Hope this helps!